# How to Filter SQL data in Python Program?

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter

I have this code, which takes data from MSSQL database and shows it in a table in my program.
My question is: How could I make a filter button so I could only show items containing "this persons name" or "this date" or "this order nr" etc if I wish?

```
def View():
    for item in set.get_children():
      set.delete(item)
      

    con1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=1.1.1.1;DATABASE=TEST;UID=#####;PWD=#####')
    cur2 = "SELECT [Date], [Order], [Position], [Client], [Product], [Operation], [Amount], [OpeningSide], [Operator], [Machine] FROM TEST ORDER BY [Date] DESC"

    cur1 = con1.cursor()
    cur1.execute(cur2)
    rows = cur1.fetchall() 

    for row in rows:

        test = row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9]
        set.insert("", tk.END, values=test) 

    con1.close()

#TABLE!
set = ttk.Treeview(ws)
set.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W), columnspan=10, rowspan=2)

set['columns']= ('Date','Order','Pos','Client','Product','Operation','Amount','Hand','Operator','Machine',)
set.column("#0", width=0,  stretch=NO)
set.column("Date",anchor=CENTER, width=80)
set.column("Order",anchor=CENTER, width=50)
set.column("Pos",anchor=CENTER, width=30)
set.column("Client",anchor=CENTER, width=110)
set.column("Product",anchor=CENTER, width=80)
set.column("Operation",anchor=CENTER, width=110)
set.column("Amount",anchor=CENTER, width=50)
set.column("Hand",anchor=CENTER, width=20)
set.column("Operator",anchor=CENTER, width=110)
set.column("Machine",anchor=CENTER, width=90)

set.heading("#0",text="",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Date",text="Date",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Order",text="Order",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Pos",text="Pos",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Client",text="Client",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Product",text="Product",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Operation",text="Operation",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Amount",text="Amount",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Hand",text="Hand",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Operator",text="Operator",anchor=CENTER)
set.heading("Machine",text="Machine",anchor=CENTER)

nupp1 = ttk.Button(ws, text="Renew", command=View)
nupp1.grid(row=3,column=5, sticky=(N, S, E, W), pady=5, padx=5)
nupp2 = ttk.Button(ws, text="Filters", command=NotFinished)
nupp2.grid(row=3,column=6, sticky=(N, S, E, W), pady=5, padx=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to define a potential SQL query as an f string:

```
sql_query = f"SELECT {criterion1} FROM PROD_MachiningEvents WHERE {criterion2};"
```

You can then design buttons that will, when clicked, assign values to the variables `criterion1` and `criterion2` depending on what you want to filter for. Then you `.execute()` and `.fetchall()` the f string and get, as a return value, a list that you can loop over to display the table.